# Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. in the Django Block

Tags: django, django-templates

I use the templates inherit with `block`:

I copy the `index.html` to `base.html`:

And add the block to the main content:

So the `base.html` is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-cn">
<head>
    <title>{{ data.info.winery_name }}</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
{% load static %}
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="renderer" content="webkit">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-siteapp" />
<link rel="alternate icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'images/favicon.png' %}">
<link rel='icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-ico' />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/default.min.css' %}" />
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]>
<script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.staticfile.org/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'lib/amazeui/amazeui.ie8polyfill.min.js' %}"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/handlebars/handlebars.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/iscroll/iscroll-probe.js' %}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/amazeui/amazeui.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'lib/raty/jquery.raty.js' %} "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/main.min.js?t=1' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="width-center">
            <div class="header-logo "><img src="{% static 'images/logo.png' %}" alt=""></div>
            <div class="header-title div-inline">
                <strong>{{ data.info.winery_name }}</strong>
                <span>{{ data.info.winery_pinyin }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="header-right">
                <span>全国咨询热线</span>
                <span>{{ data.info.country_tel }}</span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-nav">
        <button class="am-show-sm-only am-collapsed font f-btn" data-am-collapse="{target: '.header-nav'}">Menu <i
                class="am-icon-bars"></i></button>
        <nav>
        <ul class="header-nav-ul am-collapse am-in">
            <li class="on"><a href="/index/" name="index">网站首页</a></li>
            <li><a href="/product/" name="show">经营酒类</a></li>
            <li><a href="/article_list/" name="new">酒类资讯</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/" name="about">关于我们</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/" name="message">联系我们</a>
                <div class="secondary-menu">

                    <ul><li><a href="message.html" class="message"></a></li></ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/message/" >留言订购</a></li>
        </ul>

        </nav>
    </div>

</header>
{% block main_content %}
<div class="am-slider am-slider-default" data-am-flexslider="{playAfterPaused: 8000 , controlNav: false, directionNav: false    }">

    <ul class="am-slides">
        {% for ban in data.banner %}

        <li><img src="{% static  ban.img %}" alt="" ></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div><div class="copyrights">Collect from <a href="http://www.cssmoban.com/" >  </a></div>
<main>
    <div class="index-only-small">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/"><span></span><p>关于我们</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/productlist/"><span></span><p>经营酒类</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/article_list/"><span></span><p>酒类资讯</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/"><span></span><p>联系我们</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="index-main-title">
        <p>关于我们</p>
        <span>{{ data.aboutus.profile }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="index-main-body">
            <ul>
                <li><img  src="{% static data.aboutus.profile_image %}"><p>工艺专业</p></li>
                <li><img src="{% static 'images/ZHIJIAN.jpg' %}"><p>质检安全</p></li>
                <li><img src="{% static 'images/GANBEI.png' %}"><p>驰名广安</p></li>
            </ul>
        <p>
             {{ data.aboutus.profile_detail }}
        </p>
        <a href="/about/">了解更多</a>
    </div>
     <div class="index-sm-banner">
         <img src="{% static 'images/smbanner.jpg' %}">
         <p>
             {{ data.aboutus.profile_detail }}
         </p>
         <span></span>
     </div>


    <div class="index-main-bottom">
        <p>经营酒类</p>
        <span>{{ data.aboutus.corebusiness_introduce }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="project-case">
        {% for wine in data.winery %}
        <div>
            <a href="/article_list/article_list_content-{{wine.id}}/">
            <img src="{% static wine.img %}">
            <div class="projec-case-right">
            <h6>{{ wine.title }}</h6>
                <p>{{ wine.content }}</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
<div class="feature">
    <img class="big" src="{% static 'images/main4.jpg' %}">
    <img class="sm" src="{% static 'images/main5.jpg' %}">
</div>

<main>
<div class="index-main-hg-title">
    <p>经营酒类</p>
    <span>{{ data.aboutus.corebusiness_introduce }}</span>
</div>
<div class="index-main-body">
    <ul>
        {% for wine in data.winery %}
        <li><img style="width:300px; height:190px;" src="{% static wine.img %}"><p>{{ wine.title }}</p><span>{{ wine.price }}</span><a href="/productlist/productdetails-{{wine.id}}">MORE</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="news-info">
    <h2>酒类资讯</h2>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {% for wine_con in data.winery_consult %}
                {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                <li class="news-left"><img src="{% static wine_con.img %}"><div><p>{{ wine_con.title }}</p><span>{{ wine_con.content }}</span><a href="/article_list/">MORE</a></div></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><img src="{% static wine_con.img %}"><div><p>{{ wine_con.title }}</p><span>{{ wine_con.content }}</span><a href="/article_list/">MORE</a></div></li>
               {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="news-dynamic">
    <h2>酒类资讯</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for wine_con in data.winry_consult %}
        <li><a href="/article_list_content-{{win_con.id}}/"><p>{{ win_con.title }}</p><i class="font">&#xe6aa;</i><span>2017/06/01</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
</main>

{% endblock main_content %}

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="footer-pc">
    <ul>
        <li><p>网站首页 | 关于我们 | 工程案例 | 新闻资讯 | 联系我们</p></li>
        <li><p>地址：{{ data.info.address }}</p></li>
        <li><P>电话：{{ data.info.telphone }}</P></li>
        <li><p>邮编：{{ data.info.zipcode }}</p></li>
        <li><span>{{ data.info.theme }}</span></li>
    </ul>
    <img src="{% static 'images/qccode.png' %}" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="footer-phone">
        <button data-am-smooth-scroll class="am-btn am-btn-success">Top<i class="font">&#xe611;</i></button>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the `index.html`:

I only remain the main content:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main_content %}
<div class="am-slider am-slider-default" data-am-flexslider="{playAfterPaused: 8000 , controlNav: false, directionNav: false    }">

    <ul class="am-slides">
        {% for ban in data.banner %}

        <li><img src="{% static  ban.img %}" alt="" ></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div><div class="copyrights">Collect from <a href="http://www.cssmoban.com/" >  </a></div>
<main>
    <div class="index-only-small">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/about/"><span></span><p>关于我们</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/productlist/"><span></span><p>经营酒类</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/article_list/"><span></span><p>酒类资讯</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact/"><span></span><p>联系我们</p></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="index-main-title">
        <p>关于我们</p>
        <span>{{ data.aboutus.profile }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="index-main-body">
            <ul>
                <li><img  src="{% static data.aboutus.profile_image %}"><p>工艺专业</p></li>
                <li><img src="{% static 'images/ZHIJIAN.jpg' %}"><p>质检安全</p></li>
                <li><img src="{% static 'images/GANBEI.png' %}"><p>驰名广安</p></li>
            </ul>
        <p>
             {{ data.aboutus.profile_detail }}
        </p>
        <a href="/about/">了解更多</a>
    </div>
     <div class="index-sm-banner">
         <img src="{% static 'images/smbanner.jpg' %}">
         <p>
             {{ data.aboutus.profile_detail }}
         </p>
         <span></span>
     </div>


    <div class="index-main-bottom">
        <p>经营酒类</p>
        <span>{{ data.aboutus.corebusiness_introduce }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="project-case">
        {% for wine in data.winery %}
        <div>
            <a href="/article_list/article_list_content-{{wine.id}}/">
            <img src="{% static wine.img %}">
            <div class="projec-case-right">
            <h6>{{ wine.title }}</h6>
                <p>{{ wine.content }}</p>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</main>
<div class="feature">
    <img class="big" src="{% static 'images/main4.jpg' %}">
    <img class="sm" src="{% static 'images/main5.jpg' %}">
</div>

<main>
<div class="index-main-hg-title">
    <p>经营酒类</p>
    <span>{{ data.aboutus.corebusiness_introduce }}</span>
</div>
<div class="index-main-body">
    <ul>
        {% for wine in data.winery %}
        <li><img style="width:300px; height:190px;" src="{% static wine.img %}"><p>{{ wine.title }}</p><span>{{ wine.price }}</span><a href="/productlist/productdetails-{{wine.id}}">MORE</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="news-info">
    <h2>酒类资讯</h2>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {% for wine_con in data.winery_consult %}
                {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %}
                <li class="news-left"><img src="{% static wine_con.img %}"><div><p>{{ wine_con.title }}</p><span>{{ wine_con.content }}</span><a href="/article_list/">MORE</a></div></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><img src="{% static wine_con.img %}"><div><p>{{ wine_con.title }}</p><span>{{ wine_con.content }}</span><a href="/article_list/">MORE</a></div></li>
               {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="news-dynamic">
    <h2>酒类资讯</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for wine_con in data.winry_consult %}
        <li><a href="/article_list_content-{{win_con.id}}/"><p>{{ win_con.title }}</p><i class="font">&#xe6aa;</i><span>2017/06/01</span></a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
</main>
{% endblock main_content %}
```

When I in the browser to access the `localhost:8000/index/`, I get the error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /index/
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/index/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag on line 9: 'static', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py in parse, line 515
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/luowensheng/Desktop/TestIOS/TestPython/gjjWeb',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.2-py2.7.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
Server time:    Thu, 17 Aug 2017 04:27:34 +0000
```

And in the browser traceback, you can see my code contains the endfor tag.

[image]

Comment: Did you try loading `static` in the template that actually uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must `{% load static %}` inside your `index.html`. Note that any `{% load YYY %}` is not inhereted by other templates. It must be declared explicit in each HTML template.